# Why after register successfully when first time login blank screen showing, after reload the page then showing the dashboard screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I have small issue in my react js application.

After register only first time login blank screen showing, after reload the page then showing the dashboard screen. Now login the next time it's working prefect. This issue is particular user-wise.

Suppose i create the another user then again come the this issue.

I'm not able to find the issue in my code. below is my code.

Login.js

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { Link, Redirect, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { login } from '../../actions/auth';
import { Col, Row, Form, Card, Button, Image, FormCheck, Container, InputGroup } from '@themesberg/react-bootstrap';
// import BgImage from "../../assets/img/illustrations/signin.svg";
import BgImage from "../../assets/img/illustrations/signin4.jpg";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faAngleLeft, faEnvelope, faUnlockAlt, faUserCircle, faUser } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { Routes } from "../../routes";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { HashRouter as Router, BrowserRouter, Route, Switch, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import ForgotPassword from "../../pages/examples/ForgotPassword"
import RegisterPage from "../../pages/examples/Signup"
import DashboardOverview from "../dashboard/DashboardOverview"
import { Provider as AlertProvider } from 'react-alert';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from '../../store';
import AlertTemplate from 'react-alert-template-basic';
import Logo from "../../assets/img/logo2.png";

import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import axios from 'axios';
toast.configure()

const alertOptions = {
  timeout: 3000,
  position: 'top center',
};

const isAuthenticated = () => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  try {
    if (token) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }
}

export class Login extends Component {

  state = {
    username: '',
    password: '',
  };

  static propTypes = {
    login: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool,
  };

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.login(this.state.username, this.state.password);
  };

  onChange = (e) => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  render() {
    if (isAuthenticated()) {
      const role_type = localStorage.getItem("role_type")
      if (role_type === "is_subuser") {
        return <Redirect to="/profile" />;
      } else {
        return <Redirect to="/" />;
      }
    }

    const { username, password } = this.state;
    return (

      <main style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${BgImage})`, backgroundSize: 'cover' }}>
        <section className="d-flex align-items-center my-5 mt-lg-6 mb-lg-5">
          <Container>
            <Row className="justify-content-center form-bg-image">
              <Col xs={12} className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <div className="bg-white shadow-soft border rounded border-light p-4 p-lg-5 w-100 fmxw-500">
                  <div className="text-center text-md-center mb-4 mt-md-0">
                    <Image src={Logo} className="md-avatar" />
                    <h3 className="mb-0">Login to Campus Cast</h3>
                  </div>
                  <Form className="mt-4" autocomplete="off" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <Form.Group id="username" className="mb-4">
                      <Form.Label>Your Username or Email</Form.Label>
                      <InputGroup>
                        <InputGroup.Text>
                          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUser} />
                        </InputGroup.Text>
                        <input type="text" autoFocus required className="form-control" name="username" onChange={this.onChange} value={username} placeholder="Username or Email" />
                      </InputGroup>
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Form.Group>
                      <Form.Group id="password" className="mb-4">
                        <Form.Label>Your Password</Form.Label>
                        <InputGroup>
                          <InputGroup.Text>
                            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUnlockAlt} />
                          </InputGroup.Text>
                          <input type="password" required className="form-control" name="password" onChange={this.onChange} value={password} placeholder="Password" />
                        </InputGroup>
                      </Form.Group>
                      <div className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-4">
                        <Card.Link className="small text-end" as={Link} to={Routes.ForgotPassword.path} onClick={() => ForgotPasswordRoute()} >Forgot password?</Card.Link>
                      </div>
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Button variant="primary" type="submit" className="w-100">
                      Sign in
                    </Button>
                  </Form>

                  <div className="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mt-4">
                    <span className="fw-normal">
                      Not registered?
                      <Card.Link as={Link} to={Routes.Signup.path} onClick={() => RegisterRoute()} className="fw-bold">
                        {` Create account `}
                      </Card.Link>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        </section>
      </main>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
});

const ForgotPasswordRoute = async () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <AlertProvider template={AlertTemplate} {...alertOptions}>
        <Router>
          <Fragment>
            {/* <Alerts /> */}
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/examples/forgot-password" component={ForgotPassword} />
            </Switch>
          </Fragment>
        </Router>
      </AlertProvider>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
}

const RegisterRoute = async () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <AlertProvider template={AlertTemplate} {...alertOptions}>
        <Router>
          <Fragment>
            {/* <Alerts /> */}
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/register" component={RegisterPage} />
            </Switch>
          </Fragment>
        </Router>
      </AlertProvider>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { login })(Login);
```

auth.js

```
// LOGIN USER
export const login = (username, password) => (dispatch) => {

  // Headers
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  };

  // Request Body
  const body = JSON.stringify({ username, password });

  axios.post(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/login-token-auth/`, body, config).then((res) => {
    localStorage.setItem("token", res.data["token"])
    localStorage.setItem('user', res.data.user.username)
    localStorage.setItem('user_id', res.data.user.id)
    if (res.data.user.is_school) {
      localStorage.setItem('role_type', 'is_school')
    } else if (res.data.user.is_subuser) {
      localStorage.setItem('role_type', 'is_subuser')
    }
    // toast(`${res.data.user.username} login successfully`)
    store.dispatch(loadProfile());
    
    dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  })
    .catch((err) => {
      toast("Invalid Username or Password")
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_FAIL,
      });
    });
};
```

Dashboard.js

```
import React from "react";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faBusinessTime, faCashRegister, faChartLine, faCloudUploadAlt, faDownload, faPlus, faRocket, faTasks, faTimesCircle, faUserShield } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { Col, Row, Button, Dropdown, ButtonGroup, Form } from '@themesberg/react-bootstrap';

import { CounterWidget, CircleChartWidget, BarChartWidget, TeamMembersWidget, ProgressTrackWidget, RankingWidget, SalesValueWidget, SalesValueWidgetPhone, AcquisitionWidget } from "../../components/Widgets";
import { PageVisitsTable } from "../../components/Tables";
import { trafficShares, totalOrders } from "../../data/charts";
import { SalesValueChart, SalesValueChartphone } from "../../components/Charts";
import Preloader from "../../components/Preloader";
import { Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import Sidebar from "../../components/Sidebar";
import Navbar from "../../components/Navbar";

export default () => {
    return (
        <Route render= { props => (
            <>
            <Preloader />
            < Sidebar />

            <main className="content" >
            <Navbar />
            < pre > </pre>
        < Row className = "justify-content-md-center" >

        <Col xs={ 12} sm = { 6} xl = { 3} className = "mb-4" >
        <CounterWidget
            category="Total Shows"
            title = "142"
            // period="Were 12 is Inactive"
            icon = { faChartLine }
            iconColor = "shape-secondary"
            />
            </Col>

            < Col xs = { 12} sm = { 6} xl = { 3} className = "mb-4" >
            <CounterWidget
            category="Subscriber"
            title = "100"
            period = ""
            icon = { faPlus }
            iconColor = "shape-tertiary"
            />
            </Col>

            < Col xs = { 12} sm = { 6} xl = { 3} className = "mb-4" >
            <CounterWidget
            category="Downloads"
            title = "100"
            icon = { faDownload }
            iconColor = "shape-tertiary"
            />
            </Col>

            < Col xs = { 12} sm = { 6} xl = { 3} className = "mb-4" >
            <CounterWidget
            category="Total hours"
            title = "50"
            // period="Feb 1 - Apr 1"
            // percentage={28.4}
            icon = { faBusinessTime }
            iconColor = "shape-tertiary"
            />
            </Col>
            < /Row>
            < div class= "card" >
            <div class="position-relative card-body" >
        <Row className="d-flex flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center py-4" >
        <Col className="d-block mb-4 mb-md-0" >
        <BarChartWidget
                title="New Users"
                data = { totalOrders } />
            </Col>
            < Col xl = { 6} xs = { 12} className = "d-block mb-4 mb-md-0" >
            <SalesValueWidget
                title="Watched Time"
        />
        </Col>
        < /Row>
        < /div>
        < /div>
        < pre > </pre>
        < div class= "card" >
        <div class="position-relative card-body" >
        <Row className="d-flex flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center py-4" >
        <Col className="d-block mb-4 mb-md-0" >
        <BarChartWidget
                title="New Users"
                data = { totalOrders } />
            </Col>
            < /Row>
            < Row className = "d-flex flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center py-4" >
            <Col className="d-block mb-4 mb-md-0" >
        <SalesValueWidget
                title="Watched Time"
        />
        </Col>
        < /Row>
        < /div>
        < /div>
        < pre > </pre>
          {/* <Component {...props} />
            <Footer toggleSettings={toggleSettings} showSettings={showSettings} /> */}
            < /main>
            < />
        )
}
/>
  );
};
```

Comment: Did you check console? What it's showing?

Comment: @SonuBamniya i have check in console res.data it's give the response proprely, what anything else should i print in console??

Comment: can you show your Dashboard Page? If it shows a white screen, there should be some errors in the console, when you are redirected to the dashboard page.

Comment: the error can be something like, `cannot read property ${x} of ${undefined or null}`

Comment: there is no error like this but i found the issue, when i register the user then after i reload the application then it's working fine. the issue is i am not reloading the application but it's necessary to reload the application ? can it's possible without reloading

Comment: It should be, can you show your dashboard component code?

Comment: @SonuBamniya sorry for late reply i have posted my dashboard component code.

Answer (score 0):

`mapStateToProps`, as it's name suggests, provides store state as props. so your `Login` component receives `isAuthenticated` as a prop. In your render method of Login component check `this.props.isAuthenticated` instead of `isAuthenticated()` so that when store state changes, Login will render again.

```js
    if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      const role_type = localStorage.getItem("role_type")
      if (role_type === "is_subuser") {
        return <Redirect to="/profile" />;
      } else {
        return <Redirect to="/" />;
      }
    }
```

Comment: tried this but not working

Comment: @KaranChaudhari do you set `isAuthenticated` to `true` on successful login? (e.g. in your LOGIN_SUCCESS )

Comment: nope where should i set auth.js or login.js??

Comment: @KaranChaudhari in the `LOGIN_SUCCESS` reducer